# CodeIgniter - Can not load custom library in MX_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

This is a library I created:

```
<?php if ( !defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart {

    public $CI;

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        // override product_name_rules to insert
        $this->product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9_ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹ';

    }

}

/* End of file MY_Cart.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/My_Cart.php */
```

And this is controller:

http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/5994/vegf.png

If I autoload this library, I get an error "Cannot access empty property". Morever, `$data` can't get full value from html code. I don't know why, I can't see something wrong.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('add_to_cart');?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $product->Id; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="<?php echo $product->tenSP; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="<?php echo $product->gia; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productImg" value="<?php echo $product->hinhAnh; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="bay" value="" title="Mua sản phẩm"/>
</form>
```

Have any idea for this problem? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The `MY_` prefix is handled magically behind the scenes. So to load that library, you simply do

```
$this->load->library('cart');
```

You can read up on it at the bottom of the ['Creating Libraries' page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) in the docs.

Comment: I change class name is ShoppingCart and do as you said but I get an error Unable to load the requested class: ShoppingCart. What is this?

Comment: If you want to extend CI_Cart, you had it right the first time. The manual spells it all out. I can only guess why your class is not loading with the different name, but I suspect your file name and class name don't match.